# Getting Data from Database with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned table:

```
ID   Type      Date                  Status1       Status2      Status3
1    458       2018-01-01 15:04:06   AAA           A            B
2    471       2017-12-31 15:04:06   AAA           A            B
3    458       2018-01-15 15:04:06   BBC           C            D
5    458       2018-01-18 15:04:06   AAA           X            D
```

There are many same value in `Type` column, i want to fetch the data with below mentioned condition:

- Where any value in `Type` (should have more than one time in table) have `Status1` as AAA and other rows with same value in `Type` are greater than Previous `Date`, with `Status2` as C and `Status3` as D together or `Status3` must be D.

Output:

```
ID   Type      Date                  Status1       Status2      Status3
1    458       2018-01-01 15:04:06   AAA           A            B
3    458       2018-01-15 15:04:06   BBC           C            D
5    458       2018-01-18 15:04:06   AAA           X            D
```

I am using below mentioned query:

```
SELECT a.ID,a.Type,a.Date,b.Status1,a.Status2,a.Status3 
From Table1 a
inner join Table2 b
on a.abc=b.xyz
inner join Table2 c
on a.efg=c.xyz
GROUP BY a.Type
HAVING Count(a.Type)>0 
AND b.Status1='AAA'
UNION SELECT a.ID,a.Type,a.Date,b.Status1,a.Status2,a.Status3
FROM Table1 a
inner join Table2 b
on a.abc=b.xyz
inner join Table2 c
on a.efg=c.xyz
GROUP BY a.Type
HAVING Count(a.Type)>0
AND a.Date > (SELECT Date From Table1 GROUP BY Type HAVING b.Status1='AAA' AND Count(Type)>0)
AND ( Status2='A' AND Status3='D' )
OR Status3='D';
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh I am using MySQL

Comment: Then you can remove the <sql-server> tag.

Comment: @jarlh Removed it.

Comment: @VectorJX, Please add Table creation and Data for the same, or add data in http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
SELECT t.* FROM `t` INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT `type` , COUNT(`type`) ct FROM t GROUP BY `type` HAVING ct > 1
) t1 
ON t1.type = t.type ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

I hope this will return what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query .
Hope this will give you the desire output .

```
SELECT 
        ID        ,
        Type ,
        Date      ,
        Status1   ,
        Status2   ,
        Status3 
FROM 
       [Tabel_Name]
GROUP BY
       Type
HAVING
       Count(Type)>0 
AND
       Status1='AAA'

UNION 

SELECT 
        ID        ,
        Type      ,
        Date      ,
        Status1   ,
        Status2   ,
        Status3 
FROM 
       [Tabel_Name]
GROUP BY
       Type
HAVING
       Count(Type)>0 
AND
       Date > (SELECT Date From [Tabel_Name] GROUP BY Type HAVING Status1='AAA' AND Count(Type)>0)
AND
       ( Status2='C' AND Status3='D' )
OR
       Status3='D'
```

Comment: How can i use Left join in this since i am getting Status1 and Status2 from other table

Comment: You can use the inner join or make the alias of the table & make the primary/foreign key condition .

Comment: I am getting `Subquery returns more than 1 row`

Comment: ok . you can update the question with proper separate tables so that I am write the query accordingly .

Comment: Did you find any way out?

Comment: I don't understand your updated question , it looks like same as that of previous.
plz share your DB schema so it would be easy to understand